# sort imported file ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, file-upload

When previously importing my CSV file the data would upload sorted, but now, for no apparent reason, it's not coming out sorted after being uploaded and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to get it to sort.

To fix this, I'm looking at my file upload code and HTML code. I built a dynamic drop down box whereby the user selects a state, which populates the next drop down box with all bank listed in that state by bank name.  I need the bank names in the second drop down box to appear alphabetically.  Previously, when I uploaded my CSV file, the bank names would appear alphabetically, but now it's not doing that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Probably something silly I'm overlooking here.

FDIC MODEL

```
  def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        attributes = row.to_hash
        attributes['state'] = State.where(name: attributes['state']).first
        Fdic.create! attributes
       end 
      end
```

HTML

```
  <h4>Select a State</h4>
<%= select_tag :state, options_for_select(State.all.pluck(:name)), include_blank: "States" %>

  <h4>Select a Bank</h4>
<%= select_tag :bank, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@states, :fdic, :name, :id, :bank), include_blank: "Select a Bank" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I right understand your problem, and if your model State looks like:

```
class State < ..
    has_many :banks
    etc..
end
```

This correction should help you, I think.

```
class State < ..
    has_many :banks, -> { order("banks.name") }
    etc..
end
```

P.S. 
If you will use `find_by` your code would be more clearer)

```
attributes['state'] = State.find_by(name: attributes['state'])
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to Ruby and my initial instinct was to add sort, sort_by or order to the controller or HTML.  Could the order be accomplished in those places too, or just the model?

Comment: @BlueDevilPride When you use `option_groups_from_collection_for_select` you work with Model `Bank`, so it's mean that you should make order in Model, in Controller you also can use `sort` or `sort_by` but only when you will work with controller)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarity.